# How to undo "Commandeer Revision" in phabricator

Tags: phabricator

By mistake I commandeered a revision in phabricator.

Can I undo this, or does the original owner have to commandeer it back?

I tried abandoning the revision but that doesn't remove me as owner, just marks it abandoned.

The owner is not displayed or editable in the edit revision page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.
You would need the original author to commandeer it back.